# How do I automatically login to another page from a Silverlight application?

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I have written a Silverlight page that acts as an Account Registration facility for an existing web application.  So it gathers the users details then submits them to the server via a WCF RIA Service where the account is created in the database.

Basically I want to automatically log the user into the application when the service returns that the registration has been successful but I am unsure how to do this.

My current thought is that if I can POST the username and password to the existing login page then everything would be fine.  However, while I can find numerous examples of how to do a HTTP post from Silverlight, they mostly seem to assume that I want to display the response within the existing Silverlight application - I don't, I want the Silverlight app to go away and I want the logged-in application to display, as if I had hit the login button on the login page.

Something along the lines of

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://mysite.com/Login.aspx", UriKind.Absolute));
```

except with posting capability.

I do not want to pass the username and password in the querystring.

Anyone know how I can do this?  Or if this not the right approach can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a form (it could be hidden) to the HTML page that is hosting the Silverlight content. Then from within Silverlight, use the DOM to programmatically submit the form.

Comment: Nice.  I didn't even consider using the containing aspx page.  I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Although the above answer helped to solve my problem, I am going to add a bit more detail for those that are having similar issues.

On the containing aspx page I added two hidden fields for username and password inside the form tag:

```
<form id="form1" style="height:100%" action="http://mysite.com/Login.aspx" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="username" name="username" />
    <input type="hidden" id="password" name="password" />
    <div>silverlight app</div>
</form>
```

Then in my Silverlight application when the service returns successfully I added the following code to login to the web application:

```
private void Logon(string username, string password)
{
    HtmlElement usernameField = HtmlPage.Document.GetElementById("username");
    usernameField.SetAttribute("value", username);

    HtmlElement passwordField = HtmlPage.Document.GetElementById("password");
    passwordField.SetAttribute("value", password);

    HtmlPage.Document.Submit();
}
```

You may have noticed above that I have removed the runat="server" on the form tag above.  I had to do this because I was getting a "**Validation of ViewState MAC failed**" error on the Login page I was posting to.  At first I tried adding this to the web.config:

```
<pages enableViewState="false" enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never" enableViewStateMac="false"/>
```

but **none** of those options made any difference.  Of course if you are using a normal HTML page then this will not be a problem.